# Change navigationBar titleView image globally

Tags: swift, ios8

I have an app that has a navigation controller and I would like to have the logo to the app in the navigation bar where the title is and I would like to do this globally.

I can change the colour globally but not the title to an image. This is what I have in my navigation controller (which I assume is where I should put it to apply it to it globally.)

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.35, green:0.64, blue:0.98, alpha:1)
```

The colour changes but no image is applied, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `pushViewController` function of your custom `UINavigationController` and assign the `imageView` to the `viewController`'s `titleView` like this:

```
override public func pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)

    viewController.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to iOS is overriding functions a good thing to be doing or is it discouraged?

Comment: If you want to change the `titleView` globally, I think this way is good.

Comment: Alternative way to do this: making a subclass of `UIViewController` as Base View Controller, then you all viewControllers should be inherited the Base, and you can execute your code in the Base's `viewDidLoad`. I prefer the way :)